# MySQL Keep Data until no child tables attached

Tags: mysql

I'm a bit of a MySQL noob so please bear with me, I'm trying to find a way to keep something in `Parent Table` and require at least one child table have a foreign key tied with it. Hopefully an example makes sense.

```
                         Parent Table
                         ------------
                         theId int
                         someValue varchar(20)
                       /       |            \
                      /        |             \
                     /         |              \
Open Table          /    Completed Table       \ Monitoring Table
------------------ /     ------------------      ------------------
childTableId int         childTableId int        childTableId int
someOtherData blob       someOtherData blob      someOtherData blob
theId int (fk)           theId int (fk)          theId int(fk)
```

I have the 3 child data's all tracking different things and those records are only present for a certain amount of time, however the parent table is always the same throughout all stages. I need a way to make sure a child data can't be deleted if it's the only child table referencing the parent table (there can be 2 at times).

Help?

Comment: keep counter(s) in the parent table and inc/dec them as you add and delete child rows ? TBH i dont understand your question :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the event (open, completed, monitoring), you'll be calling one of these:

```
DELETE FROM Open
WHERE theId = 'yourId'
AND theId IN
    ( SELECT theId FROM Completed ) UNION ALL
    ( SELECT theId FROM Monitoring );

DELETE FROM Completed
WHERE theId = 'yourId'
AND theId IN
    ( SELECT theId FROM Open ) UNION ALL
    ( SELECT theId FROM Monitoring );

DELETE FROM Monitoring
WHERE theId = 'yourId'
AND theId IN
    ( SELECT theId FROM Open ) UNION ALL
    ( SELECT theId FROM Completed );
```

This will delete a record only if an identical `theId` is found in another table. You have to run this within a transaction. Otherwise, several users may be deleting a record with identical `theId` in different tables simultaneously.

Comment: So I'd just have to modify the select statements to add `WHERE theId = 1` or whatever, as I want to remove select rows not all the rows?

Comment: Just add `AND theID = whatever`